# TFS 2018 Burndown chart

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, burndowncharts

What is the "Ideal Trend" line in TFS Sprint burndown chart based out of? Original Estimate or Remaining Work?

If I add more tasks mid sprint, my remaining work line will show a bump. Will the starting point of "Ideal trend" line also move up in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some explanation here: [Sprint Burndown (Scrum)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/sprint-burndown-scrum?view=tfs-2018).

> The Ideal Trend line indicates an ideal situation in which the team
>   burns down all of the effort that remains at a constant rate by the
>   end of the sprint.

It is based on `Remaining Work` and represent how you have to update your `Remaining Work` in your sprint to get 0 hours of work at the end of a sprint. If you add new tasks after sprint start you will have non ideal line that adopted to new number of hours of tasks and duration of a sprint.